# Django. How to validate and save many models with OneToOne relation?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the model( this just example in real life model is much bigger):

```
class Ride(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='dives')
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    referenceA = models.ForeignKey(
        RefA,
        related_name="rides",
        blank=True,
        null=True
    ) 

    # in real life there is much more options and group of option
    optionA = models.FloatField(
        blank=True, null=True
    ) 
    optionB = models.FloatField(
        blank=True, null=True
    )
```

I have divided this model like this:

```
class Ride(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='dives')
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    referenceA = models.ForeignKey(
        RefA,
        related_name="rides",
        blank=True,
        null=True
    ) 
    ride_options = models.OneToOneField(
        RideOption
    ) 

class RideOption(models.Models):
    optionA = models.FloatField(
        blank=True, null=True
    ) 
    optionB = models.FloatField(
        blank=True, null=True
    )
```

Now I want to create a page which edit Ride model instance with all related model instances(RideOption, ...).
I prefer to use ModelForm for each model but how can I validate it all together.
I can write this validation in view, something like this:

```
ride_form = RideModelForm(...)
ride_option_form = RideOptionModelForm(...)
if ride_option_form.is_valid():
    if ride_form.is_valid():
        # now save
```

but as for me it's really ugly and I can have a lot of related model.

Is there a way to hide this validation and saving internal?

I looked on FormSet but as I understand they works only for Models with Foreign relation.
Maybe somebody knows how to  solve this with formset?
Or another(not ugly) way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want an Inline Formset

"Inline formsets is a small abstraction layer on top of model formsets. These simplify the case of working with related objects via a foreign key."
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

A `OneToOneField` is just a special case of `ForeignKey` and ought to work the same.

eg

```
# forms.py
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

from .models import Ride, RideOption

RideFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Ride, RideOption, extra=0)


# views.py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from .forms import RideFormSet
from .models import Ride

def myview(request, ride_id):
    ride = get_object_or_404(Ride, pk=ride_id)
    formset = RideFormSet(data=request.POST or None, instance=ride)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        # maybe redirect to success url here
    # else render template here
```

Comment: Now I'm trying to use them, but I will be happy If somebody post a link to example or just say that it is a good a way to do this stuff in Django

Comment: Yes, this is the 'Django way' - you need an Inline formset. Have updated the answer with example code

Comment: Ok, sorry. You don't understand me because I ask question unproperly. Now I will edit question